# IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster | hadoop 2.4.0

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, hadoop2

I am trying to run a Map-reduce using hadoop 2.4.0
My code has some dependencies on third-party jar's, So I created a FAT jar using eclipse export->runnable Jar option.

Now when I run the FAT jar using

```
       hadoop jar ~/Documents/job.jar
```

I get the exception

```
      java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

The above exception is caused by this:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1255)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1251)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1250)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1279)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
at imgProc.MasterClass.main(MasterClass.java:84)
... 10 more
```

hadoop classpath

```
hduser@livingstream:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop classpath
/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop-`2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar`
```

My configuration files

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>


</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoop/data</value>
</property>



</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
  <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>localhost:8025</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>localhost:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>localhost:8050</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I am not really sure what is going on now , Is it because of the JARs or my config files.
Anybody has anyidea , anything is appreciated ! :)

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score -2):

Error message cleary states that,

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
```

You have to configure the `mapred-site.xml and core-site.xml` and many other configurations you should do..
For step by step, you refer this link [Hadoop V2 setup](http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I edited the question with my config sites.
I think they look correct , maybe you can have a look and see something I am missing

Comment: Configuration files seems correct.can you check `imgProc.MasterClass.main(MasterClass.java:84)` line what it is calling ? and paste the snippet of it where it is throwing the Exception. what is the complete command you are using to run the job ?